# Anchor tag creating automatically inside php variable which contains generated html

Tags: php, iframe, anchor

I searched around a bit before asking this, but couldn't find anything really relevant:

My problem is as follows: I'm creating (with php) an automated email that sends to a user the html code for an iframe that he has to embed in his website. But here's what happens:

The code i create (simplified in order to contain only the src tag) is like

```
<iframe src="http://blabla.php?arg1=xx&arg2=yy"></iframe>
```

I then place the code in a textarea tag.

But when the email arrives, my code has an extra anchor tag which I never placed, as follows:

```
<iframe src="<a href='http://blabla.php?arg1=xx&arg2=yy">http://blabla.php?arg1=xx&arg2=yy</a></iframe>
```

Any ideas why this happens and how I can get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the email client trying to be helpful. Not sure there's much you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks John... i was afraid so.

Comment: It's either the client, or the WYSIWYG editor adding the HTML. If you use a WYSIWYG editor, try to view the source and edit it out.

Comment: Thanks Rob but I write the code entirely "by hand"...